# Show that any element in $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F})$ is contained in the finite union of elements of $\mathcal{F}.$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be any family of subsets of some underlying set $X,$ and let $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F})$ be the ring of sets generated by $\mathcal{F}.$ Show that for any $E \in \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F}),$ $E \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i$ where $\{F_i\}_{i=1}^n \subseteq \mathcal{F}.$ The definition of a ring of sets being used is a collection of sets which contains the empty set and is closed under finite union and set difference.

My original attempt at the proof was by contradiction:

Assume that there exists $E \in \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F})$ with $E \not\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i$ for any finite collection of elements of $\mathcal{F}.$ Then for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ we have $E-F \neq \emptyset.$ Now let $E' = \bigcap E-F$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F},$ and let $\mathcal{R}'$ be the collection of all sets in $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F})$ that are disjoint from $E'.$ Then $\mathcal{R}'$ is a ring containing $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{R}' \subset \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F})$ this contradicts the definition of $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F}).$

Obviously the problem is that $E \not\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n F_i$ is not enough to guarantee that $E'$ is not empty. So $\mathcal{R}'$ might be equal to $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{F}).$ I ended up using a different proof but I want to know if there is a way to make my original idea work, maybe using the fact that $\{E-F : F \in \mathcal{F} \}$ has the finite intersection property.